# Preparing for graduation: Election coming on August 3, 2015

Tags: discussion, election

Recently we've been [separating the elements of graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) so that beta sites get features of full-fledged communities as they need them. Our design team has been chipping away the backlog of site designs, but they aren't quite ready to release anything for Computer Science—Stack Exchange yet.

We know that you all have been [waiting a long time](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/when-will-cs-se-graduate) for graduation and the ["temporary" moderators](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) have been serving this site for over 3 years. Under our [new graduation criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) this site has been ready for graduation for quite some time, so we are going to begin gathering **nominations for moderator on August 3**. The timing should be particularly good since veteran users will be returning from their summer breaks (in the [Northern Hemisphere](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/) of course) but the regular start-of-the-school-year surge of new users won't have discovered the site quite yet.

If you are interested in running for moderator, now is the time to prepare your nomination. If you aren't interested, now is the time to bug your favorite users to prepare their nominations. ;-)

Comment: is this a full graduation or a partial graduation? are the point privilege threshholds going to shift after graduation? announcement leaves open basic misc questions. how many mod(s) are planned for the graduated site? what is the plan wrt the current mods?

Comment: @vzn: We are planning to do a complete graduation with a design soon. ([6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/1438) applies.) The privilege levels will be raised at that time. We are electing 3 moderators and the pro tempore mods are free to run if they wish. The primary purpose of this announcement is to give everyone time to prepare their nominations.

Comment: @JonEricson "pro tempore mods are free to run if they wish" -- wait a second. Does that mean the community does not necessarily get rid of us, even if they do not re-elect us pro-tem mods?

Comment: @Raphael: As a matter of procedure, after the election is finished we demod all existing community moderators. So if you don't want to be a moderator anymore, all you got to do is avoid getting elected. ;-)

Comment: still find this hard to follow. are nominations made as answers to this question, or do they not open to aug 3rd via some other interface? are you asking for some kind of responses on this question? JE your last comment also seems hard to follow. re "avoid getting reelected" does that mean existing mods have to be renominated to get reelected? can you clarify nomination convention/ procedure? a person nominates oneself or someone else right?

Comment: @vzn: Sorry for the confusion. Nominations need to be made between August 3 and 10 on [this page](http://cs.stackexchange.com/election/1). This post is merely advisory.

Comment: ok. that page only seems to indicate ppl can ["nominate"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nominate) themselves. is there any convention for "nominating" people other than oneself?

Comment: @vzn: Not really. Chat is probably the best venue, however.