# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Computer Science's [first moderator election](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Raphael] [image: D.W.] [image: Gilles]

They'll be appointed as [moderators](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

This is a good time to acknowledge our [*pro tempore* moderators](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) who worked so hard to guide this site from early public beta to the first election. In particular, please thank [Patrick87](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/69/patrick87) who is stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5472196633821184/0).

Comment: Cheers! Congratulations to our new elected mods. :) Thanks also to Juho, Luke, and tanmoy for volunteering to be mods.

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new moderation overlords ;)! (Actually seriously, well done all, and here's to CS in general).

Comment: For reference, see [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/cast-your-votes-in-the-moderator-elections-before-august-17) for a list of meta posts related to the election.

Comment: Thank you, everybody, for the resounding vote of confidence. And now back to doing more of the same...

Comment: Congratulations everyone :)

Comment: My most sincere congratulations to everyone! Keep up the good job! CS rocks!